# BitBoard class In TypeScript for chess logic

Tags: beginner, comparative-review, typescript, chess, bitset

I'm working on writing a Chess Logic Library in JavaScript for learning purposes and was wondering how good these two slightly different implementations of a BitBoard are.

The first stores the board as a 64 length string of zeros and ones and the second uses an Array containing 8 numbers each representing a byte. The body of each is mainly methods to allow for binary operations between two BitBoards or a BitBoard and a number representing an index where the operation is performed against 1.

Is this the best way to represent an unsigned 64 bit number in JavaScript?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated since I'm fairly new to programming.

**String BitBoard**

```
/**
 * 
 * @class BitBoard
 * @param bitRows: [optional] Array<number>
 * Each number must be an INTEGER in the range of 0-255; i.e. each number is a byte
 * DEFAULT: bitRows = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].length = 8; i.e. 8 bytes)
 * Each value: n is converted to an integer and then set to 0 if n > 255
 */

class BitBoard {

  public board: string;
  public length: number;

  /**
   * @param bitRows: Array<number>
   */
  constructor(bitRows: number[] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) {
    if (!Array.isArray(bitRows) || bitRows.some(x => typeof x !== 'number')) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid Input. Must be "Array" of "numbers"')
    }

    for (let i: number = 0, length: number = bitRows.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (Math.floor(bitRows[i]) !== bitRows[i] || bitRows[i] < 0 || bitRows[i] > 255) {
        throw new RangeError('inputs to bitRows array must be integers greater than or equal to zero and less than 256')
      }
    }
    
    this.board = bitRows.map(byte => padString(byte.toString(2), 8, '0', true)).join('');
    this.length = this.board.length;
  }

  /**
   * @param bit: Object
   * @returns boolean
   */
  determineIfBitBoard(bit: BitBoard): boolean {
    const names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bit);
    if (typeof bit === 'object' && names.indexOf('board') !== -1 && names.indexOf('length') !== -1) {
      const isLengthByteMultiple: boolean = bit.length % 8 === 0;
      const isBoardString: boolean = typeof bit.board === 'string';
      const isBoardLengthCorrect: boolean = bit.board.length === bit.length;
      const doPrototypesMatch: boolean = Object.getPrototypeOf(bit) === BitBoard.prototype;

      return isLengthByteMultiple && isBoardString && isBoardLengthCorrect && doPrototypesMatch;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param index: number
   * @returns number
   */
  getIndex(index: number): number {
    if (Math.floor(index) === index && index > -1 && index < this.length) {
      return parseInt(this.board[this.length -  1 - index]);
    }
    throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length');
  }

  /**
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  copy(): BitBoard {
    let newBoard = new BitBoard();
    newBoard.board = this.board;

    return newBoard;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  and(bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();

    if (typeof bitBoardOrIndex === 'number') {
      if (bitBoardOrIndex >= 0 && bitBoardOrIndex < this.length) {      
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length')

    } else if (this.determineIfBitBoard(bitBoardOrIndex)) {
      if (this.length === bitBoardOrIndex.length) {
        let str: string = '';
  
        for (let i: number = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          str += String(parseInt(newBoard.board[i]) & parseInt(bitBoardOrIndex.board[i]));
        }
        newBoard.board = str;
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('BitBoard lengths do not match');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be of type "BitBoard" or "number"');
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  or(bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();

    if (typeof bitBoardOrIndex === 'number') {
      if (bitBoardOrIndex >= 0 && bitBoardOrIndex < this.length) {

        const start: string = newBoard.board.slice(0, this.length - bitBoardOrIndex - 1);
        const altered: string = String(parseInt(this.board[this.length - 1 - bitBoardOrIndex]) | 1);
        const end: string = newBoard.board.slice(this.length - bitBoardOrIndex);

        newBoard.board = start + altered + end;

        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length');

    } else if (this.determineIfBitBoard(bitBoardOrIndex)) {
      if (this.length === bitBoardOrIndex.length) {
        let str: string = '';

        for (let i: number = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          str += String(parseInt(newBoard.board[i]) | parseInt(bitBoardOrIndex.board[i]));
        }
        newBoard.board = str;

        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('BitBoard lengths do not match');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be of type "BitBoard" or "number"');
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  xOr(bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();

    if (typeof bitBoardOrIndex === 'number') {
      if (bitBoardOrIndex >= 0 && bitBoardOrIndex < this.length) {

        const start: string = newBoard.board.slice(0, this.length - bitBoardOrIndex - 1);
        const altered: string = String(parseInt(this.board[this.length - 1 - bitBoardOrIndex]) ^ 1);
        const end: string = newBoard.board.slice(this.length - bitBoardOrIndex);

        newBoard.board = start + altered + end;

        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length');

    } else if (this.determineIfBitBoard(bitBoardOrIndex)) {
      if (this.length === bitBoardOrIndex.length) {
        let str: string = '';

        for (let i: number = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          str += String(parseInt(newBoard.board[i]) ^ parseInt(bitBoardOrIndex.board[i]));
        }
        newBoard.board = str;

        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('BitBoard lengths do not match');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be of type "BitBoard" or "number"')
  }

  /**
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  not(): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();
    let str: string = '';

    for (let i: number = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      str += newBoard.board[i] === '1' ? '0' : '1';
    }
    newBoard.board = str;

    return newBoard;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param shiftAmount: number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  shiftLeft(shiftAmount: number): BitBoard {
    if (typeof shiftAmount === 'number') {
      if (shiftAmount >= 0 && shiftAmount <= this.length) {
        let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();
  
        newBoard.board = padString(newBoard.board, this.length + shiftAmount, '0', false).slice(shiftAmount);
  
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('Invalid input. Must be greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to BitBoard.length');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be "number"');
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param shiftAmount: number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  shiftRight(shiftAmount: number): BitBoard {
    if (typeof shiftAmount === 'number') {
      if (shiftAmount >= 0 && shiftAmount <= this.length) {
        let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();
  
        newBoard.board = padString(newBoard.board, this.length + shiftAmount, '0', true).slice(0, this.length);
  
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('Invalid input. Must be greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to BitBoard.length');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be "number"');
  }
}

/**
 * @param str: string
 * @param length: number
 * @param padValue: string
 * @param start: boolean
 * @returns string
 */
function padString(str: string, length: number, padValue: string, start: boolean): string {
  if (start) {
    for (let i: number = str.length; i < length; i++) {
      str = padValue + str;
    }
  } else {
    for (let i: number = str.length; i < length; i++) {
      str += padValue;
    }
  }

  return str;
}

export = BitBoard;
```

**Number Array BitBoard**

```
/**
 * 
 * @class BitBoard
 * @param bitRows: [optional] Array<number>
 * Each number must be an INTEGER in the range of 0-255; i.e. each number is a byte
 * DEFAULT: bitRows = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].length = 8; i.e. 8 bytes)
 * Each value: n is converted to an integer and then set to 0 if n > 255
 */

class BitBoard {

  public board: Array<number>;
  public length: number;
  private bitsPerByte: number;

  /**
   * @param bitRows: Array<number>
   */
  constructor(bitRows: number[] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) {
    if (!Array.isArray(bitRows) || bitRows.some(x => typeof x !== 'number')) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid Input. Must be "Array" of "numbers"')
    }

    for (let i: number = 0, length: number = bitRows.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (Math.floor(bitRows[i]) !== bitRows[i] || bitRows[i] < 0 || bitRows[i] > 255) {
        throw new RangeError('inputs to bitRows array must be integers greater than or equal to zero and less than 256')
      }
    }
    
    this.board = bitRows;
    this.length = this.board.length * 8;
    this.bitsPerByte = 8;
  }

  /**
   * @param bit: Object
   * @returns boolean
   */
  determineIfBitBoard(bit: BitBoard): boolean {
    const names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bit);
    if (typeof bit === 'object' && names.indexOf('board') !== -1 && names.indexOf('length') !== -1 && names.indexOf('bitsPerByte') !== -1) {
      const isLengthByteMultiple: boolean = bit.length % 8 === 0;
      const isBoardArray: boolean = Array.isArray(bit.board);
      const isBoardValidNumber: boolean = bit.board.every(b => typeof b === 'number' && b >= 0 && b <= 255 && Math.floor(b) === b);
      const isBoardLengthCorrect: boolean = bit.board.length * 8 === bit.length;
      const doPrototypesMatch: boolean = Object.getPrototypeOf(bit) === BitBoard.prototype;

      return isLengthByteMultiple && isBoardArray && isBoardValidNumber && isBoardLengthCorrect && doPrototypesMatch;
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  /**
   * @returns string
   */
  boardToString() {
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
      str += padString(this.board[i].toString(2), this.bitsPerByte, '0', true);
    }
    return str;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param index: number
   * @returns number
   */
  getIndex(index: number): number {
    if (Math.floor(index) === index && index > -1 && index < this.length) {
      const powOfTwo = 2 ** (index % this.bitsPerByte);
      const numberOfBuckets = this.length / this.bitsPerByte;
      return (this.board[numberOfBuckets - 1 - Math.floor(index / this.bitsPerByte)] & (powOfTwo)) / powOfTwo;
    }
    throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length');
  }

  /**
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  copy = (): BitBoard => new BitBoard(this.board.slice());

  /**
   * 
   * @param bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  and(bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();

    if (typeof bitBoardOrIndex === 'number') {
      if (bitBoardOrIndex >= 0 && bitBoardOrIndex < this.length) {
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length')

    } else if (this.determineIfBitBoard(bitBoardOrIndex)) {
      if (this.length === bitBoardOrIndex.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
          newBoard.board[i] &= bitBoardOrIndex.board[i];
        }
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('BitBoard lengths do not match');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be of type "BitBoard" or "number"');
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  or(bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();

    if (typeof bitBoardOrIndex === 'number') {
      if (bitBoardOrIndex >= 0 && bitBoardOrIndex < this.length) {
        const numberOfBuckets = this.length / this.bitsPerByte;
        newBoard.board[numberOfBuckets - 1 - Math.floor(bitBoardOrIndex / this.bitsPerByte)] |= 2 ** (bitBoardOrIndex % this.bitsPerByte);

        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length')

    } else if (this.determineIfBitBoard(bitBoardOrIndex)) {
      if (this.length === bitBoardOrIndex.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
          newBoard.board[i] |= bitBoardOrIndex.board[i];
        }
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('BitBoard lengths do not match');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be of type "BitBoard" or "number"');
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  xOr(bitBoardOrIndex: BitBoard | number): BitBoard {
    let newBoard: BitBoard = this.copy();

    if (typeof bitBoardOrIndex === 'number') {
      if (bitBoardOrIndex >= 0 && bitBoardOrIndex < this.length) {
        const numberOfBuckets = this.length / this.bitsPerByte;
        newBoard.board[numberOfBuckets - 1 - Math.floor(bitBoardOrIndex / this.bitsPerByte)] ^= 2 ** (bitBoardOrIndex % this.bitsPerByte);

        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('index must be integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than BitBoard.length')

    } else if (this.determineIfBitBoard(bitBoardOrIndex)) {
      if (this.length === bitBoardOrIndex.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
          newBoard.board[i] ^= bitBoardOrIndex.board[i];
        }
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('BitBoard lengths do not match');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be of type "BitBoard" or "number"');
  }

  /**
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  not(): BitBoard {
    let strBoard: string = this.boardToString();
    let newStr: string;
    let notBoard: Array<number> = [];
    let i: number = 0

    while (i < this.length) {
      newStr = '';

      while(i % this.bitsPerByte !== 0) {
        newStr += strBoard[i] === '1' ? '0' : '1';
        i++;
      }
      notBoard.push(parseInt(newStr, 2))
    }
    const newBoard = this.copy();
    newBoard.board = notBoard;
    
    return newBoard;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param shiftAmount: number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  shiftLeft(shiftAmount: number): BitBoard {
    if (typeof shiftAmount === 'number') {
      if (shiftAmount >= 0 && shiftAmount <= this.length) {
        let str: string = this.boardToString();
        str += '0'.repeat(shiftAmount);
        str = str.slice(shiftAmount);

        let newBoard = this.copy();
        
        for (let i: number = 0, b = 0; i < this.board.length; i++ , b += this.bitsPerByte) {
          newBoard.board[i] = parseInt(str.slice(b, b + this.bitsPerByte), 2);
        }
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('Invalid input. Must be greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to BitBoard.length');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be "number"');
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param shiftAmount: number
   * @returns BitBoard
   */
  shiftRight(shiftAmount: number): BitBoard {
    if (typeof shiftAmount === 'number') {
      if (shiftAmount >= 0 && shiftAmount <= this.length) {
        let str = this.boardToString();
        str = '0'.repeat(shiftAmount) + str;
        str = str.slice(0, this.length);

        let newBoard = this.copy();

        for (let i = 0, b = 0; i < this.board.length; i++ , b += this.bitsPerByte) {
          newBoard.board[i] = parseInt(str.slice(b, b + this.bitsPerByte), 2);
        }
        return newBoard;
      }
      throw new RangeError('Invalid input. Must be greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to BitBoard.length');
    }
    throw new TypeError('Invalid input. Must be "number"');
  }
}

/**
 * @function padString: function
 * @param str: string
 * @param length: number
 * @param padValue: string
 * @param start: boolean
 * @returns string
 */
function padString(str: string, length: number, padValue: string, start: boolean): string {
  if (start) {
    for (let i: number = str.length; i < length; i++) {
      str = padValue + str;
    }
  } else {
    for (let i: number = str.length; i < length; i++) {
      str += padValue;
    }
  }

  return str;
}

export = BitBoard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main attractions of a bitboard are, to put it shortly:

1. Use the bit-parallel nature of bitwise operations to replace some simple loops.
2. Use the power of arithmetic operations to replace non-trivial algorithms (eg [o^(o-2r)](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Subtracting_a_Rook_from_a_Blocking_Piece)).

If a bitboard is emulated with a binary string, neither of those is realized. Effectively what you're dealing with then is a boolean array, but stored in a string. I think it misses the point. Bitboards aren't nice just because they encode the data in ones and zeroes, they're nice because they can be operated on in a computer-friendly way, and that property is lost.

The array of numbers based board does a bit better, it can get at least *some* use out of its encoding. It can do some operations on 8 cells at the time. The code is still very "stringy" in some places (shifts, `not`) but that could be improved. This isn't the full power of bitboards, but it isn't *none* of it either, sort of in between.

> Is this the best way to represent an unsigned 64 bit number in JavaScript?

Unfortunately this is a difficult problem. But there are alternatives.

A `BigInt` has no problem storing a 64bit integer. There have been some performance issues with manipulating lots of tiny instances `BigInt`, I just did some quick tests to see if it had changed, but they were not encouraging. Also, browser support for it is not universal. Perhaps this will be a good approach someday.

For now a better alternative is: use a pair of numbers, each storing 32 bits. That way you get the maximum use out of the 32bit bitwise operations that JavaScript can perform. Even emulating 64bit addition/subtraction (for the more advanced bitboard techniques) seems reasonable. For example [Scala.js](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/10d67c9e479b40714a9e134522a181829b8f64bc/library/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/runtime/RuntimeLong.scala) uses such an approach for its 64bit integers.

Comment: Whats the best approach for performing operations when numbers overflow into negatives for any number >= 2^31=2147483648 or for small numbers you NOT?  E.g. ~n =  negative number; AND, OR, and XOR return negative numbers for n >= 2^31. Also how would you approach the carrying of bits shifted off from one bucket into another? I chose 255 to be the max per bucket so you would never get negative numbers from any operation. I see the negative numbers posing a problem if you want to convert the board to a string since (1+n).toString(2) === (~n).toString(2).slice(1)

Comment: @casual234 you could use the `>>> 0` trick before calling `toString`

Comment: I updated the bitboard based on your advice; should I post it here for an updated review?

Comment: @casual234 not in the same post, but in a new one sure go ahead

Comment: Here's the [new version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230052/bitboard-class-in-typescript-for-chess-logic-follow-up)